# Monotone class theorem to show the property for nonnegative measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

The Monotone Class theorem:

> Suppose $\mathcal{A}_0$ is an algebra, $\mathcal{A}$ is the smallest σ-algebra containing $\mathcal{A}_0$, and $\mathcal{M}$ is the smallest monotone class containing $\mathcal{A}_0$. Then $\mathcal{M}=\mathcal{A}$.

Suppose we want to prove a property $P$ for all nonnegative $\mathcal{S}$-measurable functions $Z$. Can we prove the property holds for simple functions or bounded continuous functions and use Monotone Class Theorem to extend the result to all nonnegative measurable functions?

I know the technique holds for bounded functions, and I wonder if we may extend it to the unbounded cases?

A similar discussion appears in
[Monotone class theorem for unbounded functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609373/monotone-class-theorem-for-unbounded-functions)
but they are talking about general measurable functions instead of nonnegative ones.